# Como saber qual o file que esta se repetindo no console.log?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Estou com um problema no meu código, onde utilizo o javascript,firebase e bootstrap.

Busco informação no firebase e tenho um "new" dentro da query que cria algumas informações no meu html. Porém se eu repetir esta função duas vezes seguidas, ele cria as informações mais de duas vezes.

Preciso saber de onde realmente vem essas repetições. Tem algum jeito?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode inserir o código? Parece ser algo relacionado com eventos, algum `listener` que você esqueceu de remover...

Comment: Mostre o seu código para que possamos lhe ajudar

Comment: @bio desculpe, não postei o código porque é corporativo e não pode ser postado. Mas caso for o que você falou, poderia me dizer como eu faço para verificar?

Comment: Percebo que o seu código é corporativo, mas você pode substituir os dados sensiveis por dados fetícios para nós termos um [exemplo verificavel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)